# newtype vs foreign import data

Tags: purescript

What are the practical reasons of choosing between these options?

For example:

1. `foreign import data Foo :: Type -> Type`
2. `newtype Foo a = Foo a`

Let's assume in both cases, we get a Foo via some function:

`foreign import newFoo :: forall a. a -> Foo a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that with `newtype` the data representation is known, and with `foreign import` it isn't.

One consequence of this is that with `newtype` you can get `a` out of `Foo a` by pattern matching:

```
let foo = newFoo 42
let (Foo fourtyTwo) = foo
```

and with `foreign import` you can't do that.

Another consequence is that with `foreign import` the function `newFoo` is free to choose representation, it doesn't necessarily have to be equivalent to that of `a`, e.g.:

```
// JavaScript
exports.newFoo = function (a) { return { wrapped: a } }
```

but with `newtype` is has to be exactly `a`:

```
// JavaScript
exports.newFoo = function (a) { return a }
```

Then there is also the convenience of automatically deriving the `Newtype` class, which opens up some automation possibilities.

---

To respond to the second question in the comments (in the future please post a separate question):

If your `Foo` did not have a type parameter, but was defined like this:

```
// Case 1
data Foo = Foo

// Case 2
foreign import data Foo :: Type
foreign import newFoo :: Foo
```

The difference here is the same as above: for `data` representation is known, for `foreign import` it isn't.

The way it can manifest in practice really depends on your context. One example I can think of is automatic derivation of `Eq`, `Show`, `Generic`, etc., which would need to be manually coded for the `foreign import` approach. Another example that comes to mind is that  `data Foo` is statically guaranteed to have exactly one value, whereas `newFoo` is free to return different values in every call.

Comment: Thanks... though now I'm even more confused, hehe... `Foo {wrapped: a}` isn't the same as `Foo a`... how can that still be legal? I assume it's connected to what you're saying about the inability to inspect the data at runtime?

Comment: There is no `Foo {wrapped :: a}`. On the PureScript side the type will still be `Foo a`, but the JavaScript implementation of `newFoo` can wrap the value any way it wants, because the representation is not visible/accessible from PureScript.

Comment: Can you please elaborate in the case of where it is just a type (not type constructor) - e.g. `data Foo = Foo` vs. `foreign import data Foo :: Type` ?

i.e. there is nothing to inspect... so what is the difference in this case?

Comment: Updated the answer